# What are the steps to create a bluetooth connection?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I need to create a Bluetooth connection between two devices (the first is an Android, and the other is an Android Wear) with Java, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: What kind of connection do you want to create? To do what? Please provide more information. These [https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer] are the official methods to send/receive data with Wear OS. A strategy could be to use Bluetooth LE, you set a GATT server on the Wear device and a GATT client on your Android phone. If you provide more info about your use case I can try to help more in detail.

Comment: @phcaze. The link you gave me is not working. I am trying to transfer data from a sensor on the smartwatch to the smartphone via bluetooth, I have already configured the sensors, but I am not able to create the bluetooth socket

Comment: Then, the best way would be to create a GATT server (https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver) on the smartwatch and a GATT client on the smartphone (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). In this way, your watch will make the data available using a standard.